# How to select a current object's value in array with js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects like so...

[Object, Object, Object]

Basically, there is a div with a click function and I want this click function to display that div's (which also has an object) specific property.

The two ways I know of, is using a for loop and defining an i variable and calling that or calling a specific object.

1. For loop method to select current object in array:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < PODS.podsData.length; i++) { 
    console.log (PODS.podsData[i].posMinimized);
    PODS.podsData[i].posMinimized = 1;
   }
   ```
2. console.log(PODS.podsData[5].posMinimized)

So is there another way of declaring the specific PODS.podsData? Basically instead of PODS.podsData[i] or PODS.podsData[5] is there another value I can put between the [] that will log the current object's value I need, like PODS.podsData[XXX] or something?

Comment: <<that will log the current object's value I need>> How do you know which object's value you need?

Comment: You can put absolutely any expression between the `[]`, and it will be evaluated, and its return value will be converted to a string to be used as the property name.

Comment: The object has many properties of which I only need the "posMinimized" one. I know the objects properties by logging the array of objects and reviewing them.

Comment: I can put anything between [] but just need to know what the selector is for the current one. For example "i" will select the current one in a for loop but I do not want to loop through all the objects in the array, Just select the current one.

Comment: You could use an data attribute/object e.g "data-index/.data('index')" and in click handler use it to target the indexed object if i follow you. The question is how do you link your array of objects with DOM objects?!

Comment: What is the "current one"? If you don't know what the current one is how are we supposed to? is the div's index related to the index of the object you're trying to access from the array?

Comment: @KevinB i think the clicked DIV

Comment: You should provide your click handler code for DIVs and how do you generate these DIV elements regarding your array of objects. Maybe you just need to use index() method.

Comment: I'm using the content from the object to append it to the div. The object properties are like this http://d.pr/i/M9Jx and I basically append "content" to a column using a for loop. But I don't need a for loop this time and just need to find a way to select the current object's "PosMinimized" value.

Comment: You need to find a way to identify which DIV is clicked regarding corresponding object in array. I know this is your question but as you still don't provide relevant code for generating these DIV elements no one could help you more... Your picture is completly useless here regarding your issue.

Comment: The generated HTML looks like this...

http://d.pr/i/qtSp

Where each pod (or widget has a "ui-minimize" button) and that is where I needed to add the click function.

Comment: Great! And **HOW** this is related to your array of objects? This is my question since 33 mins...

Comment: These are hard coded HTML templates where the whole template is appended to an object's "content" property and then that whole object is stored in an Array. Then I call that array and sort each objects data accordingly. For example the "content" property is called in a for loop where it takes the entire HTML template and appends it to a column.

Comment: The wierdest question i have ever seen on this site. you need to learn how to explain the (issue) your having instead of getting people to guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try that: *{maybe...}*

```
$('.pod').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var posMinimized = PODS.podsData[i].posMinimized;
        //do some stuff with current clicked element
    });
});
```

But i still don't understand your issue...

Comment: Ah ha! Perfect so basically missing the simple idea of assigning a click function to each and THEN assigning the i value for each. Thanks!

Comment: Ha ok, now i better undestand what was your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

**NO** you have to provide the name of the item to be able to get the item.

`PODS.podsData[5] // will work`

`PODS.podsData['Please get me number 5'] // Wont work`

So to get the 5th item in the array you must provide the number 5 unless you have a object like this

```
   var podsData = {
        coolName: {
          posMinimized: 1
        }
    }
```

Then you would use

`podsData.coolName.posMinimized` or `podsData['coolName].posMinimized`

to get the result

Comment: This is how the current naming is. I don't think either one of those solutions work for me because I want to select "this" objects posMinimized value. http://d.pr/i/M9Jx

Comment: @Connor OP is refering to clicked element in click handler i think, but is question is really too vague

Comment: That is not `this` that is `PODS.podsData` if it were `this` you wouldn't have the 3rd object open because that wouldn't represent `this`